# Visual Studios Unit Test File Path annoyance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am using MS Unit Tests in VS2010.

I created a class that reads a file..just a static word list. The file was added to the main project and the test project as content with "Copy always" selected as the build event.

When I run the unit test, however, it looks for the file in the output directory of the unit test. How do you make it look in the bin directory. I don't want to mess with absolute filepaths just for testing...

```
Test method RequiredServicesTest.RequiredServices_JamesTest.Number2WordsTest threw exception:



Test method RequiredServicesTest.RequiredServices_JamesTest.Number2WordsTest threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file E:\scomA3proj\TestResults\James_JAMES-PC 2012-02-24 21_22_17\Out\randomdictionary.txt.
```

Update: One thing I forgot to mention is that this is a WCF Service Library project.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541096/visual-studio-unit-tests-loading-resources-in-the-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to store my test files as an embedded resource in the test class and extract them to a temporary directory (with auto clean up / delete functions) so I never have to worry about where the files live.  It seems to be easier and more stable this way.

Answer (score 4):

Please consider the following trick to get the right path:

```
var assembly = typeof(RequiredServices_JamesTest).Assembly;
var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(assembly.EscapedCodeBase).LocalPath);

var filePath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "randomdictionary.txt");
// You have the correct file path now!
```

Comment: For one, the project should not need to know about the test project.

Comment: I see. You can try to set the current directory from your test method to assemblyPath. Then, the rest of your production code will stay intact.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the word list file a deployment item, then it gets automatically copied into your test output directory.

```
[TestClass()]
[DeploymentItem("randomdictionary.txt")]
public class SomeTestClass
{
   //..
}
```

Comment: Should work fine, make sure file is in the project root directory otherwise it won't be found. Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I added that to the class as well as the individual method. I added the randomdictionary.txt file directly to the test project too. [TestMethod()]
        [DeploymentItem("randomdictionary.txt")]
        public void Number2WordsTest()
        {

Comment: It gets copied to the test projects "bin" folder but it tries to find the file in the test output directory..

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a "WCF Service project" that I am testing...maybe it does not work for that...

Answer (score 0):

I resolve using this article
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx

One example to keep it simple

1. inside the root dir of **UnitTestProject1** I have test data in dir **TestData** (it contains at this stage of development all directory and file useful for test). **Inside** **TestData** i have a dir **TestCollisioni**

   Direcotry path:
   **UnitTestProject1**|->**TestData**|->**TestCollisioni**
2. My command onPostBuild event (this is documented on link above) for xcopy test files is (you need to modify only **UnitTstProject1** and **TestData** value if needed (i.e.  only if you use a different test Project Name or a different TestData dirname)).

   xcopy /Y /S "$(SolutionDir)**UnitTestProject1**\**TestData***" "$(TargetDir)**TestData**\"

   Using $(SolutionDir) and $(TargetDir) seems best way to autodeploy test file, don't change it
3. Test Method have this value for DeploymentItem

   ```
   [TestMethod]

   [DeploymentItem("TestData")]
   ```
4. Inside test you can access file inside test data (and whatever inside that dir) as , for example:

   Directory.Exists(@"**TestCollisioni**\"),

So my working test test is (NO "\" Before **TestCollisioni**) :

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem("**TestData**")]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Directory.Exists(@"TestCollisioni\"));
    }
```